# why do it get : when i press git log command

Tags: git, command-line

When to press git log command to see all the commits made, I get to see -->

```
commit: bla bla
Author: bla bla
Date: bla bla 
:
```

it's ok to see this information but after last `:`  I can't type anything. If I try to type anything I get to see `(END)` with a error sound nothing else. I can't use git any more I have to force exit console and restart everything to again use git. What am I supposed to type after `:` so I get out of it ?

Comment: Yaa worked thanks. How could I forgot that. Use something like that in Vim to quit. But why does this show up @user3159253

Comment: Try get familiar with `vi` or `less` command on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` you see is the command prompt for the pager that is loaded to read the log. It is most likely `less`; which is the default that git uses. To exit the prompt type `q`

You can configure this setting with [`core.pager`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Basic-Client-Configuration) property.

For example, if you set it to be blank:

```
git config --global core.pager ""
```

Then you will see all the log messages at once, without any pagination; that is, without the `:` prompt. However, you may want to keep it as is, and instead learn these useful shortcuts:

```
g: go top of the file
G: go bottom of the file
/: search forward
?: search backward
N: show line number
: goto line
F: similar to tail -f, stop with ctrl+c
S: split lines
```

There is a lot more information at the [man page for `less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less).

Comment: Yes, but that won't affect what the log message output does; that just affect what default editor is used when you want to write commit messages.

Comment: It's worth adding here that the key difference between a "pager" (like `less`) and an "editor" (like `vim`) for this particular usage is that the pager will read from a pipe (and start as soon as it has a page's worth of text to show), while the editor requires a complete file.